# How do you tell if a node is on the screen spritekit swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to figure out how to determine if a node is visible on the screen or off the screen. Is this just a true/false property of the node?
Thanks. (Using swift spritekit)

Comment: No, there is no any property on node which indicate that sprite is on or off the screen. Also there isn't any notification when node leaves screen.  You should calculate it by yourself. You can start with this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25044232/3402095 Other possible solution is to create edge based physics body around the scene, and when node leaves the screen didBeginContact will be triggered (which, I guess, can be a more performant solution) Search SO about this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the following to test if a node is in the scene:

```
if (!intersectsNode(sprite)) {
  println("node is not in the scene")
}
```

This assumes that `self` is an `SKScene` subclass, such as `GameScene`.

Comment: So this doesn't seem to work if your node is a child of another node, how would I check this then? Eg: I have a node called backgroundNode whos position is the middle of the screen (the anchor point of the scene is the bottom left (0, 0)). then i add my child node to backgroundNode. Now the position of my child node is (0, 0) which is the center of my backgroundNode, so it appears in the middle of the screen. The problem is that as I apply a force to this child node, its position becomes negative, and since the scene frame starts from (0, 0), intersects will return false. How do I handle this?

Comment: @Minimi try setting `backgroundNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)` and `backgroundPoint.position = CGPoint.zero`. You may need to change the position of the child node, accordingly.

Comment: the background node is a SKNode, they don't have anchor points. I ended up using a relative frame adjusted for the anchor point (same size as screen, but origin is negative). I then use intersects with this new relative frame.

Answer (score 6):

the best answer here will be:

```
if scene.frame.contains(myNode.position) {
//do stuff
}
```

"intersect" method is very heavy and involves too much computing, can produce lag if used on many instances

Answer (score 3):

If you put a SKCameraNode in the scene, you can check if a node is inside the view of the camera using the `contains` method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skcameranode

You can also get all the nodes visible to the camera using the `containedNodeSet` instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly but you could use its position to check. Therefore you might do something like:

```
if (/*the node's position is between 0 and the screen's .x and .y*/) {
    //on screen
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: It was more supposed to give him an idea than actual code. I changed it to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CGRectIntersectsRect` supplying the `frame` of your `SKSpriteNode` and the `SKScene`. For example:

```
if !CGRectIntersectsRect(frame, spriteNode.frame) {
    // Outside the bounds of the scene because the frames are no longer intersecting.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `SKScene` fits within its containing `view`, this should work:

```
if !node.intersectsNode(node.parent!) {
     // node is off-scene/out-of-view
}
```

where `node` is an `SKNode` that is the child of your `SKScene`.