# SKSpriteNode doesn't delete when falls off scene

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

My app (Swift 2) doesn't delete any nodes when they fall off of the scene. Eventually they'll take up space and down the framerate. My code can be found at https://github.com/Ph0enix0/Loominarty-Confirmed/blob/master/Loominarty%20Confirmed/GameScene.swift Thank you!

Comment: The code you've linked does nothing except rotating sprites, means they never leave the screen. Anyways, if you want to remove the node from parent after it leaves screen, you can do it in a few ways : 1) use intersectsNode() method, 2) use action sequence(and remove node after certain event), 3) use physics border around the scene and detect contacts which will indicate that node is off-screen. You can start here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/30551951/3402095

Comment: Shit, sorry. I used the wrong file. Uploading project files now. Damn github for mac took the hello world program thats default on xcode.

Comment: Fixed it now! I forgot to press the Sync button on github for mac. Good job, me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your situation, based on how you move bullet, the easiest solution would be to use action sequence. Like this :

```
func SpawnBullets(){
    var bullet = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 20))
    bullet.zPosition = -5
    bullet.position = CGPointMake(player.position.x, player.position.y)



    let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30.0, duration: 0.6)

    let remove = SKAction.runBlock({bullet.removeFromParent(); println("Bullet removed from scene")})

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([action,remove])

    bullet.runAction(sequence)

    bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bullet.size)
    bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physCat.bullet
    bullet.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physCat.enemy
    bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    self.addChild(bullet)
}
```

You are probably aware of this, but not hurt to mention that removing off-screen nodes is a good habit because every node added to the node tree stays there and consumes resources until it is removed.

Comment: would i remove 'bullet.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))', or did you forget to add that line?

Comment: Removing the line mentioned above would prevent the enemies from spawning. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need repeatActionForever actually.  Just copy and paste my code. Basically you create an action to move bullet from point A to point B. No need for repeating that forever. Also, consider not using NSTimer to repeat spawning...You should do all that with actions. NSTimer don't respect scene's, node's or view's paused state.