# Determine if SKNode is in front of camera view (ARKit Spritekit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, arkit

I'm trying to detect when the camera is facing my object that I've placed in ARSKView. Here's the code:

```
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
        guard let sceneView = self.view as? ARSKView else {
            return
        }

        if let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame {
            //let cameraZ =  currentFrame.camera.transform.columns.3.z
            for anchor in currentFrame.anchors {
                if let spriteNode = sceneView.node(for: anchor), spriteNode.name == "token", intersects(spriteNode) {
                    // token is within the camera view
                    let distance = simd_distance(anchor.transform.columns.3,
                                                 currentFrame.camera.transform.columns.3)
                    //print("DISTANCE BETWEEN CAMERA AND TOKEN: \(distance)")
                    if distance <= captureDistance {
                        // token is within the camera view and within capture distance
                        print("token is within the camera view and within capture distance")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the intersects method is returning true both when the object is directly in front of the camera, as well as directly behind you. How can I update this code so it only detects when the spriteNode is in the current camera viewfinder? I'm using SpriteKit by the way, not SceneKit.

Here's the code I'm using to actually create the anchor:

```
        self.captureDistance = captureDistance
        guard let sceneView = self.view as? ARSKView else {
            return
        }

        // Create anchor using the camera's current position
        if sceneView.session.currentFrame != nil {

            print("token dropped at \(distance) meters and bearing: \(bearing)")

            // Add a new anchor to the session
            let transform = getTransformGiven(bearing: bearing, distance: distance)
            let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: transform)
            sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
        }

        func getTransformGiven(bearing: Float, distance: Float) -> matrix_float4x4 {
        let origin = MatrixHelper.translate(x: 0, y: 0, z: Float(distance * -1))
        let bearingTransform = MatrixHelper.rotateMatrixAroundY(degrees: bearing * -1, matrix: origin)
        return bearingTransform
    }
```

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551951/how-do-you-tell-if-a-node-is-on-the-screen-spritekit-swift ?

Comment: @GrahamPerks not quite

Comment: I stopped playing with SpriteKit, could you tell me if your "camera" for your sceen is your ARCamera?  if it is, SKCameraNode has a containsNode function to determine of a node is on the scene

Comment: currentFrame.camera is ARCamera. where would I find the camera as SKCameraNode?

Comment: Ahh found it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscene/1519696-camera

Comment: So it seems to have the same effect as the intersects() method. It returns true both when the node is in front of camera view, as well as directly behind.

Comment: it shouldnt have the same effect, intersect only compares the frame

Comment: Maybe these methods are returning true when object is directly behind you because of the way I'm adding it. I'll update my post with the code I'm using to drop my anchor/node.

Comment: I can tell you in your original code your intersects is always going to be true since you are saying scene intersects node, meaning it only fails if the node is not in the bounds of the game scene. Does `ARKit` give you an `SKCameraNode` for free?  Does the position values change when you move the camera?  My guess is going to be no, since `ARKit` is actually 3d, it is capturing your 3d world space, and then converting it to the static scene position,  But if that is the case, then `self.camera!.contains(spriteNode)` should only work with what is on screen

Comment: No, intersects is not always true. It's true in the cases I said, which is when the object is visible in front of you in the camera view, and also the exact opposite when it's behind you.

Comment: It is probably not true because the node is not attached to the actual scene until you hit a certain point in the ARCamera space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent a while looking at this, and have come to the conclusion that trying to get the distance between the `currentFrame.camera` and the `anchor` doesn't work simply because it returns similar values irregardless of whether the `anchor` is infront of, or behind the camera. By this I mean that if we assume that our anchor is at point x, and we move forwards 1meter or backwards 1 meter, the distance from the camera and the anchor is still 1 meter.

As such after some experimenting I believe we need to look at the following `variables` and `functions` to help us detect whether our `SKNode` is infront of the camera:

(a) The `zPosition` of the SpriteNode which refers to:

> The z-order of the node (used for ordering). Negative z is "into" the screen, Positive z is "out" of the screen

(b)  `open func intersects(_ node: SKNode) -> Bool` which:

> Returns true if the bounds of this node intersects with the
>   transformed bounds of the other node, otherwise false.

As such the following seems to do exactly what you need:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    //1. Get The Current ARSKView & Current Frame
    guard let sceneView = self.view as? ARSKView, let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame else { return }

    //3. Iterate Through Our Anchors & Check For Our Token Node
    for anchor in currentFrame.anchors {

        if let spriteNode = sceneView.node(for: anchor),  spriteNode.name == "token"{

            /*
             If The ZPosition Of The SpriteNode Is Negative It Can Be Seen As Into The Screen Whereas Positive Is Out Of The Screen
             However We Also Need To Know Whether The Actual Frostrum (SKScene) Intersects Our Object
             If Our ZPosition Is Negative & The SKScene Doesnt Intersect Our Node Then We Can Assume It Isnt Visible
            */

            if spriteNode.zPosition <= 0 && intersects(spriteNode){
                print("Infront Of Camera")
            }else{
                print("Not InFront Of Camera")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this function to check the camera's position :-

```
- (void)session:(ARSession *)session didUpdateFrame:(ARFrame *)frame; {

       simd_float4x4 transform = session.currentFrame.camera.transform;

       SCNVector3 position = SCNVector3Make(transform.columns[3].x,
                                         transform.columns[3].y,
                                         transform.columns[3].z);

       // Call any function to check the Position.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would give you a clue. Check the ZPosition like this.

```
    if let spriteNode = sceneView.node(for: anchor), 
       spriteNode.name == "token", 
       intersects(spriteNode) && spriteNode.zPosition < 0 {....}
```